# Displaying displayName and email from FirebaseAuth gives error in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I want to display the displayName and email from FirebaseAuth on an app screen but when I try to put them into Text() widgets I get an error.

Here is the error:

> The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
>
> User? get currentUser

Here is the code where I am trying to do this:

```
 UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: Text(auth.currentUser!.displayName),
              accountEmail: Text(auth.currentUser!.email),
            ),
```

I have tried a few different things but nothing gets rid of the error.

How do I get this to work?
Thanks

Comment: Try asking this to ChatGPT

Comment: `displayName` isn't guaranteed to exist as a string value.  You have to check that and decide what you want to do if it's not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you got the error is `Text` widget only accept `String` which can not be null. But `displayName` or `email` in your code is null.

Try this:

```
accountName: Text(auth.currentUser?.displayName ?? '')
accountEmail: Text(auth.currentUser?.email ?? '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: Text(auth.currentUser!.displayName),
              accountEmail: Text(auth.currentUser!.email),
            ),
```

I would assume that this callable `Text` expects values of type `String` not `String?` for `accountName` and `accountEmail`. The difference here is the question mark `?` at the end of the type name which indicates that is nullable.

https://dart.dev/null-safety

Nullable means that the value accepts a null value but Text expects non-nullable and you are passing values of type `String?` to it which is causing this compiler error. Check if this works:

```
UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
  accountName: Text(auth.currentUser?.displayName ?? 'No display name'),
  accountEmail: Text(auth.currentUser?.email ?? 'No email'),
),
```

The `?.displayName` tries to find the `displayName` attribute under `currentUser` and if it is not found it returns a null value and `??` returns the value after it if the value before it is null.